# Issue in retrieving All users from a Person or Group type column using C# COM for each List Item

Tags: development, document-library, client-object-model, user-accounts

I have a requirement like this: There is a SharePoint 2013 document library, say, MyReports. MyReports has a column "AssignedToUsers" which is of type Person or Group (multiple selections enabled). Now the requirement is that for each list item in MyReports, those user(s) should be able to view the list item if his/her name is there in "Assigned to Users" column of that list item and he should not be able to view any other list items of the library. And I need to achieve this using C# COM coding. Please help me out.

Comment: Are you asking how to accomplish this as a whole, or just the CSOM portion?

Comment: you can achieve the OOTB by setting the filter on views.

Comment: @wjervis - I am a SharePoint newbie. It will be really helpful if you can give me the whole idea. Thanks in advance.